# can't send mails using flask, any ideas?

Tags: python-2.7, flask

L.T:
 Ok now it works. I had to instantiate Mail() class after configuration(ie. app.config) :)

i have this error:

```
    host = smtplib.SMTP(self.mail.server, self.mail.port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I'm trying to build a site for myself, and i'm stuck at the part of sending e-mails because of the above error. Thing is i opened my port (that's because i'm behind a router). One thing to note is that using 'standalone' smtplib works but the one from flask doesn't. I'll post what works and does not. I don't know what is the problem. I modified address from socket.py to my 'localhost' and port 465 because i thought that was the problem. Hence i tried almost everything i could but in avail. Could someone help me a little bit here? Thanks.

This doesn't work(hello.py):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_mail import Message
from flask.ext.script import Manager
import os

mail = Mail()
app = Flask(__name__)

mail.init_app(app)
mail = Mail(app)
manager = Manager(app)
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    msg = Message('Hello',
                   sender = 'my_mail@gmail.com',
                   recipients = ['my_mail@gmail.com'])
    msg.body = 'testing'
    msg.html = '<b>testing</b>'
    mail.send(msg)

app.debug = True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

And tried a more minimalist way to see if this works, and it works, i can send mail to myself(mail.py):

```
import smtplib
from hello import app

gmail_user = app.config['MAIL_USERNAME']
gmail_pwd = app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']
FROM = 'my_mail@gmail.com'
TO = ['my_mail@gmail.com']
message = 'test'

server_ssl = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
server_ssl.ehlo() # optional, called by login()
server_ssl.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)  
# ssl server doesn't support or need tls, so don't call server_ssl.starttls() 
server_ssl.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
#server_ssl.quit()
server_ssl.close()
print 'successfully sent the mail'
```

Bump...

Comment: Although you *can* put functions into a list, that's **not** what's happening here - you're putting the *value returned by the function* into the list. You could have written `l_shoplist = [raw_input() for _ in range(4)]` instead, by the way.

Comment: hm..i was thinking that "everything is an dict in python", rather that `object` :). About usage of functions for list creating, it's not especially about python, same will work for any language: java, c, c#, etc ... as was answered above - function return value which is assigned as initial value.

Comment: @Reishin no, everything (including `dict`!) is an object, although there is plenty implemented using dictionaries behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with objects. Functions are designed the way they return a value, and you can assign that value the same way you put the input into the list.

You just run the function, take the value it returned and put it into the variable.